# How to update the number on navMenuIcons

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer

`OnCreate` I do:

```
incidentItem = new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1));
navDrawerItems.add(incidentItem);
```

and in

`onPostExecute`:

```
incidentItem = new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], 
                                 navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1), true, "10");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it does not work, no error, no update.

Comment: if I add it again `navDrawerItems.add(incidentItem);` it will add it to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is an ArrayList (or another type of list). ArrayLists do not function as normal arrays, and can not be accessed as such.

Try this:

```
navDrawerItems.add(0, incidentItem);
```

Helpful ArrayList Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to update the counter in your navigation drawer item. Therefore you should not use `.add(incidentItem)` but `.set(1, incidentItem)`, which replaces the old item with the new one.

You can also look these methods up here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html